# Как сохранить изображение с примененными к нему css фильтрами?

Tags: css

Как сохранить изображение с примененными к нему css фильтрами?

Comment: alt+prtScr

Comment: Если нужно автоматизировать - phantomjs в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю Spectre, alt+prtScr